# Preventing decimal number in value

Tags: php

I need to know how to prevent user from inserting decimal number.

What I mean with decimal number is like 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.2, 3.4 from the selected option:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

injected into

```
<option value="1,5">1</option>


  $quantity = $_POST['esquantity'];
```

I need to check it here:

```
   if ($quantity ......) { }
```

Thanks in advance:

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for the quick answer. Can you please tell me how to use it?

Comment: Zeeshan, `intval()` does not return a boolean

Comment: @alisa Have you seen my answeR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php).

An int is always an whole number and cant be a decimal.

You can use it like this:

```
$quantity = $_POST['esquantity'];

if(is_int($quantity) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: yes I have voted it up, but I have not checked it. Skip it a moment.

Comment: @alisa Thank you, is this your desired result though? It returns an boolean as stated in your question?

Comment: It is me who should thank you. Btw, that's it, I want to know what does the code mean? It returns true or false? What I want is when there is a decimal number it return false. `if(is_int($quantity) {
    echo "please input correct value";
}` Thanks again.

Comment: Then you can do something like this: `if(!is_int($quantity)) {...}` This checks if the statement is false (so that its not an int)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to check like this:

> if (in_array($quantity , array(1,2,3,4,5))) { ... }

This checks if the quantity is within the allowed values. Replace array(1,2,3,4,5) with the allowed values in your case.